# Triggering a simple onchange method using jquery in .NET WebForms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, onchange

I'm trying to trigger a simple event/preview of the image when the user tries to upload it, after the preview (Cropping and editing it he'll click save). What I've and what I'm trying so far is following:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
           function  loadImage(event) {
                var output = $('#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>').val();
                output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
            };
        }); 
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

And ont he HTML side I have the file upload control like following:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" onchange="loadImage(this)" runat="server"  /></div>
```

But when I try to select the image I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: loadImage is not defined(…)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `loadImage` in this case is a local function and onchange cannot find it.  move it out of your `ready` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant assign the read value from file input to image . you have to read data first like below

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $('input[type="file"]').change(function(){
            readURL(this);
        });
        }); 
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#output').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file"/>
<img id="output" src=""/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `$.ready` call since you are just defining the function.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script>
           function  loadImage(event) {
                var output = $('#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>').val();
                output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
            };
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```